# How to get row number for a string in qtablewidget

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt 5.4.0 and created a QTableWidget. The table has several rows and columns.

In my application I want to search a string in that table and if that string exists, I want to know the row number.

I could not find any such api in qt 5.4.0 documentation.

Does anyone has understanding of such api or similar to what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`match()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match) method of the model:

```
for (int col=0; col<tableWidget->columnCount(); col++){
    // return a list of all matching results
    QModelIndexList results = tableWidget->model()->match(
        tableWidget->model()->index(0, col),
        Qt::DisplayRole,
        "yourstring",
        -1,
        Qt::MatchContains
    );
    // for each result, print the line number
    for (QModelIndex idx : results)
        qDebug() << idx.row();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the columns and call `match()` function multiple times. It's sufficient to call `tableWidget->model()->match()` function only once for the model index (0, 0).

Comment: @vahancho, In the doc, it's write *"Returns a list of indexes for the items in the **column** of the start index"*

Comment: Yeah, but you can use `Qt::MatchRecursive` flag to search the whole table starting from the upper left cell (row=0, col=0).

Comment: @vahancho, with ```Qt::MatchContains | Qt::MatchRecursive``` doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use [findItems method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#findItems):

```
QString searchtext = "text";
QList<QTableWidgetItem *> items = ui->tableWidget->findItems(searchtext, Qt::MatchExactly);
for(int i=0; i<items.count(); i++)
{
    int row = items.at(i)->row();
    //...
}
```

Notice that you can pass an extra argument to `findItems`, to set one or more [match flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MatchFlag-enum).